# SQL Server: Login failed for user 'testing'

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2017

This occurs on a new installation of SQL Server 2017 when attempting to log in and issue queries from `cmd` via `sqlcmd`.

The problem occurs with ANY local or domain accounts. However I am now focusing on a single local account named 'testing', with a relatively easy to type password of 'test'.

```
C:\sqlcmd -S WIN-CERULEAN-22 -U testing
Password:
```

Entering the correct (or incorrect) password yields:

```
Password: Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server: Login failed for user 'testing'..
```

[image]

If I change the Server string to something that doesn't exist, I get a login timeout failure (as expected).

The account 'testing' has sysadmin role assigned.

[image]

The 'testing' account is granted permission to connect to database engine, and Login is enabled.
[image]

The SQL Server instance has been restarted multiple times throughout troubleshooting.  The host OS (Server 2022) was restarted at least once to rule that out.

I've compared every user setting with this new installation against a known good/working installation and am unable to see any differences. I am able to login on the known good/working SQL Server instance with a local account there without issue.

What am I missing here to cause SQL Server to reject a known good password?

---

edit - @RossBush with the save. Needed to change this setting to SQL Server and Windows Authentication.  Made that change, restarted SQL Server, and am able to log in to the 'testing' account.

[image]

Comment: Check the SQL Server logs and get the true authentication error. If you don't understand that error, then [edit] your post to include that error.

Comment: Is Mixed mode authentication enabled?

Comment: @RossBush where in settings is this found?

Comment: I see a backslash in your screenshot. Is the server you're connecting to really `WIN-CERULEAN-22` or a specific named instance on that machine (`WIN-CERULEAN-22\something`)? Leaving out the instance name only works if the instance happens to be listening on the default port (1433).

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, that is the server name. I also tried connecting with localhost (127.0.0.1) same login denied errors. If I change one letter of the server string to something invalid, the login times out.

Comment: The question was not about the server name but the instance. It's possible to be able to connect to both `WIN-CERULEAN-22` and `WIN-CERULEAN-22\InstanceName` without these being the same SQL Server.

Comment: @a coder - Right click the instance tree view node. Select the "Properties" context menu item to display the Instance "Properties" Dialog. Select the "Security" List View Item from the List View menu on the left side the Properties dialog. Check the "Server authentication" radio button selection.

Comment: @RossBush that did it. If you want, please type this up as an answer so I can credit this as the correct solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When users who have been properly provisioned against a SQL Server database can't connect, one thing to always check is if mixed mode authentication is enabled. To check this value, select the instance and bring up the properties dialog and select properties. The available values under "Server authentication" are:

- Windows Authentication mode
- SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

If you want users to be able to connect using SQL Server logins, make sure that the second option is checked.

If this is the case then after the .. in this error you posted -> "SQL Server: Login failed for user 'testing'..", you should see verbiage to along the lines of "if using a sql server login then make sure mixed mode authentication is enabled".

Comment: I just started getting the same error again (login failed for user, with a known good password). AFAIK, the only change made to the system recently was a new server IP to move us to a different switch.  Confirmed that `SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode` is still checked.

Comment: @acoder - Is it the same user account and same password. You said a different server, did you double check the user account?

Comment: same account. I did restore the database from backup, however I confirmed that all of the user accounts exist (including the ones that are returning invalid login).

Comment: Is there anything in place to rotate the passwords?

Comment: No, they are service account pw, set to never expire or change.

Comment: hmmm, can you post the entire exception?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be typing a hostname instead of a full SQL instance name. I cannot see what the full name of your SQL instance in your screenshots, but that's your problem.

Syntax should be something like:

`sqlcmd -S WIN-CERULEAN-22\INSTANCE_NAME -U testing`

Comment: I've tried the full SQL instance name: `sqlcmd -S WIN-CERULEAN-22\JTINSTALLATION -U testing`, and continue getting the same invalid password error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case database was not exist.
I created the database then run sqlcmd.
it works.